# OS agnostic connection to MySQL database via Matlab

Tags: mysql, matlab

I am trying to setup a database via MySQL and connect to that database using some Matlab code. I notice that there are multiple documentation pages for using Matlab to setup a connection to a MySQL database:

- https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-jdbc-linux.html
- https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-jdbc-windows.html

Is there a way to connect to a MySQL database in an OS agnostic manner using Matlab? I am trying to provide open source code that (I think ideally) uses a MySQL database, and would like to find a way around constraining users around any particular OS. That is, I'll provide some instructions with my code that tells the user how to setup a local database via MySQL, and my Matlab code will be used to analyze data and store different program configurations/experiments in the database. I suppose I could also try turning to some other database software, but based on my previous readings it seems like MySQL might be the best way to go about this. I'm getting no suggestions from the Matlab community and hoping to find some help here.

Comment: Looking at the links you posted it seems that connecting from the command line is similar. Perhaps you can just include the connection that way in your script, and have a dialog asking for database, username etc.  (It's been some 30 years since I used Matlab, so I may completely misunderstand what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: The only distinction MySQL cares about is "localhost" vs hostname+port-number and a TCP/IP connection.  So, what problem leads you to ask about "OS Agnostic"?

Comment: I must admit I am rather new to database terminology and may have misinterpreted something. You're basically saying that--while the process to originally setup your database (and use in Matlab) is different between Linux and Windows--I won't need any special code to connect to a database on either Windows or Linux. That aspect will just involve the database() function.

Comment: I struggle to find differences between the two pages you linked.

Comment: Ha! I think you may be right. How bizarre. I guess my question should have been--why is Matlab's documentation like this?